# Is there a program that can (re)create a form (using HTML / Swing) using OCR from a screenshot?

Tags: forms, code-generation, ocr, image-recognition

I have a set of screenshots from a legacy Desktop application that needs to be redeveloped for the web

Although HTML will be used, the end result would have almost the same layout, and same fieds

I was wondering, just like OCR can detect a scanned document's text, tables and even form elements, is there any product that can take a (very accurate and clean by nature) screenshot and create the HTML that will put text fields, drop downs, checkboxes, radio buttons and labels in the same layout as the source screenshot form? I know its techncally feasible, and can be quite accurate, but couldn't find one

It is beyond my current skills to venture into image recognition, otherwise I would have given it a shot

Comment: I think you'd have somewhat better luck finding a tool to convert an existing desktop application project (in Visual Studio, for instance) to a web application project.

Comment: I actually know personaly someone who worked in a Startup that is doing / did that, but I have no access to that system. just screen shots of very clear, alighned, easy to OCR, standard UI forms. many of them (500 fields in total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be possible - screenshots do not include enough information eg form validation, fields which are shown/hidden based on other options, tooltips, etc.

That said, you can make a form VERY rapidly using something like ASP.Net MVC eg:

Model:

```
Public Class MyFormModel
    <Required()>
    Property Username as string

    <Required()>
    Property Password as string

    Property DOB as DateTime

End Class
```

And then in a view:

```
<%: html.EditForModel() %>
```

Which would generate the entire form based on the model - and as you can see the model is very easy to define...

Comment: I would not expect it to do nothing but layout, all validation, binding, etc, will be done manually of course. but there is already the technology to do just label, location and field type, and for a form of 150 fields, bealive me, I prefer to write this tool than do it all by hand. and this is one form out of many totaling hundreds of fields. just getting the label name in the right  location will be good enough. and any OCR can probably do that... just need it to be output in HTML

Comment: Understood - I don't know of any tool which will do exactly what you want and suspect coding it would be difficult. If I were in your shoes, I'd seriously consider the cost trade-off between writing the software and hiring some students to do data entry but without knowing the exact scale of your problem, it's hard to advise. If you do find a tool which does this, I'd be very interested in it/